# Avoid libraries binding in jar file upon building maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I have made a spring project and created a seperate directory for libraries/dependencies but whenever i build the project libraries are included in jar file along with being copied in libraries directory which resulted in increasing my jar file size to 47 MB. I want my jar to read libraries from directory mentioned in **pom.xml** file but jar file must not have libraries in it.

Following is the build tag of my **pom.xml** file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <!--<goal>copy-dependencies</goal>-->
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/lib
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.kalsym.requestresponsesimulator.RequestResponseSimulatorApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: If you are on spring boot you don't need maven-depenendecy-puing nor maven-jar-plugin. Only use spring-boot-maven-plugin for packaging...read the docs. I'm not sure but it sounds as if you misunderstood the concept of spring boot projects because it's intended to create a single executable jar which can be started by `java -jar ...` which includes everything...reading from lib directories is unusual...If this is not the case than it would be helpful to describe your needs and reasons to go that unusual way..

Comment: Actually in my case frequent changes in project are required and for testing purpose jar has to be uploaded to LINUX server. Large file takes time to upload, so i need to upload libraries only once then each time only jar without libraries is to be uploaded

Comment: First why uploading to a server for testing? Don't you use unit- integration testing ? Furthermore I strongly recommend to take a deep look into spring-boot-maven-plugin because it has several options to support layers (usually related to docker) but that can help in such cases as well...